# Asp.net Multiview Word Wrap Problem (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio, multiview

I am using ASP.net MULTIVIEW control, but when I enter text in one of it's VIEW the **text got expanded beyond specified width** i.e. 200px in Visual Studio. What I want is to wrap the text within container. Here is the code. You can simply paste it in Visual Studio to see the problem.

```
<div style="width: 200px">
  <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
      <p>
           In ipsum risus, luctus eu lobortis eu, ultricies nec diam. Pellentesque non pharetra
           odio. Etiam nisi felis, sagittis sit amet tempor sit amet, lacinia et mauris. Sed
           id dui nisl, vitae pellentesque sapien. Sed justo elit, mattis a ornare egestas,
           congue id tortor. Donec pharetra est sit amet augue scelerisque ultrices. Sed ac
           urna nulla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
           cubilia Curae; Maecenas risus quam, adipiscing non euismod ut, luctus ac magna.
           Curabitur id nulla at magna vehicula scelerisque ac gravida ipsum. Integer non tellus
           tortor.
      </p>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
      some text here
    </asp:View>
  </asp:MultiView>
</div>
```